# bitbake clean fails with read-only NFS SSTATE CACHE

Tags: caching, yocto, nfs, bitbake

I am trying to set-up a read-only SSTATE cache where several jobs will the reading from this cache to accelerate the build.

`bitbake -c clean <recipe-name>` fails. I would like to clean the current work directory for the current recipe and not clean the SSTATE cache. (I have a master job that populates this cache). Did anyone have come across this issue? Of-course, we can remove the `SSTATE_DIR` and issue the command but I was wondering if there are better solutions. Thanks

LOGS:

```
ERROR: Build of do_clean failed
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "sstate_eventhandler(e)", line 13, in sstate_eventhandler
...
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/mnt/nfs/yocto_build/sstate-cache/d6'

ERROR: Task 0 ( recipe-name.bb, do_clean) failed with exit code '1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its a read-only sstate archive, use SSTATE_MIRRORS instead.